# :empty selector with jQuery on a form element?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Is there a way I can use a jQuery selector like `:empty` or `:not(:checked)` on an input/textarea/select element, or any other way I can return an object that is empty?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely clear, but I think you're looking for input controls that have no value entered by the user?  There's no explicit selector/filter for that, but...

You can build a custom filter by using the `.filter()` function on your result set.  Try something like:

```
$("input").filter(function (){
    return $(this).val() == '';
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested it but this should work too

```
$('input[value=""], select[option=""]')
```

as selector.

Comment: Oddly, the jQuery input selector requires a semicolon before it as in $(':input[value=""]') http://api.jquery.com/input-selector/

Comment: Well I'm matching by element, your comment yields to the jQuery extension ":input" thats a difference.